# Is it possible to widen a message box in MFC?

Tags: mfc

I display a message box using the **AfxMessageBox** keyword. Basic stuff.

But, due to the length of the path, it displays like this:

[image: Message Box]

Is there any way that I can stop it from word wrapping that way?

Sorry if this is a dumb question. But if I have a single sentence it would normally show wider.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[AfxMessageBox](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/as6se7cb.aspx) eventually calls [MessageBox](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645505.aspx). There is no way for an application to (easily) modify, how the system displays the message box.

If you need a custom message box dialog, you will have to implement your own.

Background information on the evolution of the layout algorithm used by the `MessageBox` was published by Raymond Chen at The Old New Thing: [Why doesn’t my MessageBox wrap at the right location?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20110624-00/?p=10343)

Answer (score 1):

You can override [`CWinApp::DoMessageBox`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cwinapp-class?view=msvc-160#domessagebox) on your derived class and supply your own message dialog, customized in the way you want. All `AfxMessageBox` calls will get your override in the way.

Comment: Thanks! I just did a test and managed to get it to use `CTaskDialog` where I can set the width. But it is a bit fiddly to decode the `nType` into the respective buttons and main icon to use. That is my only issue now.

Comment: Please see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66013767/converting-a-afxmessagebox-into-a-ctaskdialog-using-domessagebox