# Converting a AfxMessageBox into a CTaskDialog using DoMessageBox

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, messagebox, taskdialog

I have written this function so far:

```
int CMFCApplication3App::DoMessageBox(LPCTSTR lpszPrompt, UINT nType, UINT nIDPrompt)
{
    CString strContent = CString(lpszPrompt);
    CString strTitle; strTitle.LoadString(AFX_IDS_APP_TITLE);
    CTaskDialog dlgTaskMessageBox(strContent, _T(""), strTitle);
    int iPixelWidth = (::GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSCREEN) / 100) * 30;
    int iDialogUnitsWidth = MulDiv(iPixelWidth, 4, LOWORD(GetDialogBaseUnits()));
    dlgTaskMessageBox.SetDialogWidth(iDialogUnitsWidth);

    /*
    if (nType & MB_ICONINFORMATION)
        dlgTaskMessageBox.SetMainIcon(TD_INFORMATION_ICON);
    if (nType & MB_ICONERROR)
        dlgTaskMessageBox.SetMainIcon(TD_ERROR_ICON);
    if (nType & MB_ICONWARNING)
        dlgTaskMessageBox.SetMainIcon(TD_WARNING_ICON);
    if (nType & MB_ICONQUESTION)
    {
        HICON hIcon = LoadIcon(IDI_QUESTION);
        dlgTaskMessageBox.SetMainIcon(hIcon);
    }

    int iButtons = 0;
    if (nType & IDYES)
        iButtons |= TDCBF_YES_BUTTON;
    if (nType & IDNO)
        iButtons |= TDCBF_NO_BUTTON;
    if (nType & IDCANCEL)
        iButtons |= TDCBF_CANCEL_BUTTON;
    if (nType & IDOK)
        iButtons |= TDCBF_OK_BUTTON;
    if (nType & IDRETRY)
        iButtons |= TDCBF_RETRY_BUTTON;
    dlgTaskMessageBox.SetCommonButtons(iButtons);
    */

    if (nType == (MB_YESNOCANCEL | MB_ICONERROR))
    {
        dlgTaskMessageBox.SetCommonButtons(TDCBF_YES_BUTTON | TDCBF_NO_BUTTON | TDCBF_CANCEL_BUTTON);
        dlgTaskMessageBox.SetMainIcon(TD_ERROR_ICON);
    }
    if (nType == (MB_YESNOCANCEL | MB_ICONWARNING))
    {
        dlgTaskMessageBox.SetCommonButtons(TDCBF_YES_BUTTON | TDCBF_NO_BUTTON | TDCBF_CANCEL_BUTTON);
        dlgTaskMessageBox.SetMainIcon(TD_WARNING_ICON);
    }
    if (nType == (MB_YESNOCANCEL | MB_ICONINFORMATION))
    {
        dlgTaskMessageBox.SetCommonButtons(TDCBF_YES_BUTTON | TDCBF_NO_BUTTON | TDCBF_CANCEL_BUTTON);
        dlgTaskMessageBox.SetMainIcon(TD_INFORMATION_ICON);
    }
    /*
    if (nType == (MB_YESNOCANCEL | MB_ICONQUESTION))
    {
        dlgTaskMessageBox.SetCommonButtons(TDCBF_YES_BUTTON | TDCBF_NO_BUTTON | TDCBF_CANCEL_BUTTON);
        HICON hIcon = LoadIcon(IDI_QUESTION);
        dlgTaskMessageBox.SetMainIcon(hIcon);
    }
    */
    return dlgTaskMessageBox.DoModal();
}
```

I have two issues with this and am happy to split as two questions:

1. Using `IDI_QUESTION` is causing the application to crash.
2. Isn't there an easier way to decode `nType` into the various buttons and icon required?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Using `IDI_QUESTION` is causing the application to crash

That's because `IDI_QUESTION` is a [standard icon](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/menurc/using-icons) and must be loaded by passing a `NULL` instance handle to [`::LoadIcon`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-loadicona), but MFC's `CWinApp::LoadIcon` passes `AfxGetResourceHandle()` instead. The following bypasses MFC and calls the Win32 API directly.

```
HICON hIcon = ::LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_QUESTION);
```

> Isn't there an easier way to decode nType into the various buttons and icon required?

Not a lot easier, but they could be grouped to lessen the duplication.

```
int nCommonButtons = 0;

switch(nType)
{
case MB_YESNOCANCEL:
    nCommonButtons |= TDCBF_CANCEL_BUTTON;
case MB_YESNO:
    nCommonButtons |= TDCBF_YES_BUTTON | TDCBF_NO_BUTTON; 
    break;

case MB_OKCANCELRETRY:
    nCommonButtons |= TDCBF_RETRY_BUTTON;
case MB_OKCANCEL:
    nCommonButtons |= TDCBF_CANCEL_BUTTON;
case MB_OK:
    nCommonButtons |= TDCBF_OK_BUTTON; 
    break;

//... etc
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I have it working now. I added my own answer too.

Comment: Glad it helped. Yours will work, too. Thing is that I am not aware of a builtin way to map between the two sets of flags, so it has to be done by hand one way or another.

Comment: I see that the TaskDialog itself has some members `CTaskDialog::GetCommonButtonFlag` and `CTaskDialog::GetCommonButtonId` but they are not accessible.

Comment: One issue, my real application also uses `MB_ICONSTOP` and I am not sure of equivalent.

Comment: @AndrewTruckle That should be `IDI_HAND` (same as `IDI_ERROR`). And those two functions wouldn't help much here, because they map between CTaskDialog styles and the standard button IDs, which don't correspond directly to the MessageBox styles.

Comment: So I should double up the `MB_ICONSTOP` tests with the `MB_ICONERROR` test really.

Comment: @AndrewTruckle Yes, the two are [the same](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-loadicona#parameters).

Comment: Doh - I did not need to update my code then - save values. Already caught.

Answer (score 3):

I thought I would add this as addition answer.

Taking onboard the accepted answer (@dxiv) and the comments that were made below (@sergiol):

```
int CMeetingScheduleAssistantApp::DoMessageBox(LPCTSTR lpszPrompt, UINT nType, UINT nIDPrompt)
{
    CString strContent = CString(lpszPrompt);
    CString strTitle = CString();

    if (!CTaskDialog::IsSupported())
        return CWinAppEx::DoMessageBox(lpszPrompt, nType, nIDPrompt);

    ENSURE(strTitle.LoadString(AFX_IDS_APP_TITLE));
    CTaskDialog dlgTaskMessageBox(strContent, _T(""), strTitle);

    int iPixelWidth = (::GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSCREEN) / 100) * 30;
    int iDialogUnitsWidth = MulDiv(iPixelWidth, 4, LOWORD(GetDialogBaseUnits()));
    dlgTaskMessageBox.SetDialogWidth(iDialogUnitsWidth);
    HICON hQuestionIcon = ::LoadIcon(nullptr, IDI_QUESTION);

    // Icon
    switch (nType & MB_ICONMASK)
    {
    case MB_ICONERROR:
        dlgTaskMessageBox.SetMainIcon(TD_ERROR_ICON);
        break;
    case MB_ICONWARNING:
        dlgTaskMessageBox.SetMainIcon(TD_WARNING_ICON);
        break;
    case MB_ICONINFORMATION:
        dlgTaskMessageBox.SetMainIcon(TD_INFORMATION_ICON);
        break;
    case MB_ICONQUESTION:
        dlgTaskMessageBox.SetMainIcon(hQuestionIcon);
        break;
    }

    // Buttons
    int nCommonButtons = 0;
    switch (nType & MB_TYPEMASK)
    {
    case MB_YESNOCANCEL:
        nCommonButtons |= TDCBF_CANCEL_BUTTON;
        [[fallthrough]];
    case MB_YESNO:
        nCommonButtons |= TDCBF_YES_BUTTON | TDCBF_NO_BUTTON;
        break;

    case MB_RETRYCANCEL:
        nCommonButtons |= TDCBF_RETRY_BUTTON | TDCBF_NO_BUTTON;
        break;

    case MB_OKCANCEL:
        nCommonButtons |= TDCBF_CANCEL_BUTTON;
        [[fallthrough]];
    case MB_OK:
    default:
        nCommonButtons |= TDCBF_OK_BUTTON;
    }
    dlgTaskMessageBox.SetCommonButtons(nCommonButtons);

    return static_cast<int>(dlgTaskMessageBox.DoModal());
}
```

I was not aware of these:

- `MB_ICONMASK`
- `MB_TYPEMASK`

---

The only scenario I have not catered for is `MB_ABORTRETRYIGNORE` because I do not see common buttons equivalents for **Abort** and **Ignore**.

Comment: Why are you mixing logic of buttons visibility with logic of icon? For icons you can do something like 
`switch (nType & MB_ICONMASK)` and for buttons `switch (nType & MB_TYPEMASK)`.

Comment: @sergiol What exactly are MB_ICONMASK etc? Are these special for retrieving the button and icon values? Where is it documented for MFC?

Comment: The documentation on those is really poor or inexistant. I remember the flags for something we have done here before, but they are essentially a mask to filter against some `MB_*` values, depending on the purpose. Sometimes the better way to know about MFC is to look to the base source code which is supplied, or to put some breakpoints in there.

Comment: @IInspectable is there any documentation you know about the `MB_*MASK` entities?